# Keep row in edit mode after inserting in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a Gridview and I have defined the respective itemtemplates and edittemplates for the rows and controls. I have different row events to bind, insert, update, delete the data from the grid. As per the requirement I am struggling to find a way to keep the new Row in edit state once it has been inserted in the grid. Presently there is an overhead of clicking the edit button after the row is inserted. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: I found a resolution. I could simply call the RowEdit Event explicitly by :
 gridView_RowEditing(sender, new GridViewEditEventArgs(gridView.Rows.Count-1));

Answer (score 0):

I found a resolution. I could simply call the RowEdit Event explicitly by : `gridView_RowEditing(sender, new GridViewEditEventArgs(gridView.Rows.Count-1));`

Comment: Then Put The  Code:-                                                                                        protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        bindGridview();
    }

Comment: Isn't the practice of calling event handler this way, explicitly & manually , a Wrong Practice ?